# Dash layout python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, plotly-dash

I've been working on a dash application and I've ran into a bit of a pickle. My main issue is with the layout - I'm trying to format a dropdown menu which permits a user to select a worksheet, and then output the contents of that worksheet on the page. However I haven't been able to format it to display on the second page; I can only make it display on every page or none at all. Here is what I currently have for the layout (IE I want this to display on the timelinesDates page) -

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=True),
    html.Div(id='page-content',
             children =[
             html.H2("Select Target Company"),
             html.Div([dcc.Dropdown(id="field_dropdown", options=[{
                               'label': i,
                               'value': i
                           } for i in dropdown_options],
                           value='Sheet3')],
             style={'width': '25%',
                    'display': 'inline-block'}),
                  dt.DataTable(rows=[{}],
                 row_selectable=False,
                 sortable=False,
                 selected_row_indices=[],
                 id='datatable')
         ])
])

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('datatable', 'rows'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('field_dropdown', 'value')])





@app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('page-content', 'children'),
              [dash.dependencies.Input('url', 'pathname')]) 

def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/' or pathname == '/overview':
        return overview
    elif pathname == '/timeline-dates':
        return timelineDates,
        def update_datatable(user_selection):
            if user_selection == 'Sheet1':
                return global_df_sheet_to_df_map.parse(0).to_dict('records')
            elif user_selection == 'Sheet2':
                return global_df_sheet_to_df_map.parse(1).to_dict('records')
            else:
                return global_df_sheet_to_df_map.parse(2).to_dict('records')  
    elif pathname == '/further-analysis':
        return furtherAnalysis
    elif pathname =='/excel-data':
        return excelData
    elif pathname == '/full-view':
        return overview,timelineDates,furtherAnalysis, excelData
    else:
        return noPage
```

Comment: Pickle usually means something else in Python-speak :)

Comment: What do you mean by "display on the second page"? Your code looks fine, but it seems like every time the user select something the drop downs disappears and gets replaced by the content you want to display. Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: I've edited a few things since then, but yes, this is exactly my intention. Well, more specifically I want the dropdown to remain, but the content to coincide to the user selection. IE. if the user selects "Sheet2" The content on page 2, which is a tabular view of the the sheet, will update to Sheet2 instead of the prior selection.